# FadeOut / FadeIn on Scroll - Fixed Value not Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently working on a site and I'm trying to move into to jquery a little bit more I pieced together a script that fades  elements on scroll. However, the values right now are fixed. I am running into these two problems:

1) Smaller views give me a delay.

2) Larger views fade out to quickly.

Here's the code:

```
        $(document).scroll(function() {    
          var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
          if (scroll > 500) {
            $("#content-slide-1").addClass("fading");
          } else {
            $("#content-slide-1").removeClass("fading");
          }
          if (scroll > 1200) {
           $("#content-slide-2").addClass("fading");
          } else {
           $("#content-slide-2").removeClass("fading");
          }
          if (scroll > 1900) {
           $("#content-slide-3").addClass("fading");
          } else {
           $("#content-slide-3").removeClass("fading");
          }
          if (scroll > 3000) {
           $("#content-slide-4").addClass("fading");
          } else {
           $("#content-slide-4").removeClass("fading");
          }
          if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 400) ) {
           $("nav").addClass("hidden");
         } else{
           $("nav").removeClass("hidden");
         }
        });
```

I am making these fade in / fade out by add/removing a class. So the question I have is there a way to make the fade more responsive? What should I do differently to make the code a bit more dynamic and more elegant if that's the right word. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/daletpainter/pen/QEgPwm)

Answer (score 0):

Look into css transitions, they wont work on older browsers but are designed for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd recommend using [Request Animation Frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of Scroll for performance, see [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/). Secondly [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) is the new age animation tool for these kind of animations.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var blockArr = [];
    var $blocks = $(".blocks");
    $.each($blocks, function(index, val) {
         var obj = {};
         obj.offsetTop = $(val).offset().top;
         obj.startAni = $(val).outerHeight(true);
    });

function callSomeFunctionEachRequestAnimationFrame() {
    var scrollTop = window.scrollTop;
    for (var i = 0; blockArr.length < i; i++) {
        if (blockArr[i].offsetTop + (blockArr[i].startAni / 2) > scrollTop) {
            // perform some kinda animation
            // e.g. add class or change css properties directly
        }
    }
}

// binds a function "raf" to window
window.raf = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame  ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); // 60 FPS
    };
})();

function loop() {
    callSomeFunctionEachRequestAnimationFrame();
    raf(loop);
}

raf(loop);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.offset().top` to get the current position of the elements *(which will change on different screens)*

```js
var $cs1 = $('#content-slide-1').offset().top, 
    $cs2 = $('#content-slide-2').offset().top, 
    $cs3 = $('#content-slide-3').offset().top, 
    $cs4 = $('#content-slide-4').offset().top;
//alert($cs3);

$(document).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > $cs1 ) {
    $("#content-slide-1").addClass("fading");
  } else {
    $("#content-slide-1").removeClass("fading");
  }
  if (scroll > $cs2) {
    $("#content-slide-2").addClass("fading");
  } else {
    $("#content-slide-2").removeClass("fading");
  }
  if (scroll > $cs3) {
    $("#content-slide-3").addClass("fading");
  } else {
    $("#content-slide-3").removeClass("fading");
  }
  if (scroll > $cs4) {
    $("#content-slide-4").addClass("fading");
  } else {
    $("#content-slide-4").removeClass("fading");
  }
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 400) ) {
    $("nav").addClass("hidden");
  } else{
    $("nav").removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.content-slide {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
  -moz-transition: all 800ms;
  -o-transition: all 800ms;
  transition: all 800ms;
}
.content-slide.fading {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
  -moz-transition: all 800ms;
  -o-transition: all 800ms;
  transition: all 800ms;
}
.content-slide.solid-dark {
  background: #60504d;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
.content-slide.solid-teal {
  background: #67baaf;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div id="content-slide-1" class="content-slide solid-teal">
 </div>
 
 <div id="content-slide-2" class="content-slide solid-dark">
 </div>
 
 <div id="content-slide-3" class="content-slide solid-teal">
 </div>
 
 <div id="content-slide-4" class="content-slide solid-dark">
  
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple solution based on a jQuery function I wrote.

```
function fadeIn(el) {
    $(el).each(function () {
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
        var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
        var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
        if (top_of_object > top_of_window) {
            $(this).removeClass("fading");
        }
        /*If it's starting to not be visible anymore, fade it out */
        if (bottom_of_object < bottom_of_window) {
            $(this).addClass("fading");
        }
    });
}
```

You can find it working on your code in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/yJXAOQ)